# Setting Line Break in High chart legend

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization

I am making a Line in highchart where there are between one and two objects and each object has multiple lines associated with it.  My issue is I want my legend to look like this:
[image]

Where color represents the object and opacity represents the actual line on the graph.  I couldn't figure out how to get the object labels "Thing one" and "Thing two" in the right place, but I hacked it together by putting the object name in the first series title and got a legend that looks like this:
[image]

This isn't the best solution, but I would be ok with it except for the fact that when the chart is resized, the line breaks in arbitrary places:
[image]

making it confusing to read.  Is there a way to set the line break so that the different objects are always on different lines if the chart is resized:

[image]

Also open to suggestions on better ways to represent this legend.

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide your config or reproduce the example in the working demo? You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/84z9rnp2/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by setting the legend itemWidth and width property:

```
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    itemWidth: 400,
    width:400,
    align: 'center'
  }
```

Comment: This did not work for me, It resulted in every label being in one column.

Comment: Yes. You can play around with itemWidth and width combination to achieve your results. This is sample config where each option would be on one separate line. Keep the width constant and try different values for itemWidth